# WPF : get value from user control to parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, parent-child, cefsharp

i've a user control which contains **cefsharpwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser** control. this UC is loaded dynamically to the main window (in tab control). 
UC gets and sets the value of var **Title** of **class DisplayHandler** which implements `IDisplayHandler, INotifyPropertyChanged` and it works fine for the UC. 
Now I want the value of **Title** either from class **DisplayHandler** or from UC in the main class to set the Header of the Tab Item.
**this code is from UC and works for Lable title**

```
<Label x:Name="title" Content="{Binding ElementName=Browser_DisplayHandler, Path=Title, TargetNullValue=TitleHere}" />
<cefsharpwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" Address="google.com"> 
     <cefsharpwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser.DisplayHandler>
         <local:DisplayHandler x:Name="Browser_DisplayHandler"/>
     </cefsharpwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser.DisplayHandler>
</cefsharpwpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

but i want this title value in main class which has a Data template designed for tab control and textblock in header is named as **txtTitle** and is bind to Header

```
<TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel Width="200" MaxWidth="200" Height="28">
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}" Width="15" Height="15">
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\Faisal\source\repos\SampleWPF\SampleWPF\delete.png" Height="13" Width="13"></Image>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" Margin="1,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        Margin="7,2"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

if i set `tab.Header = "Tab Title";`from its main class that works but i want Title from class **DisplayHandler**

```
string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
```

Please help me to achieve this by using code behind technique or Binding in WPF
thanks

Comment: How are you setting DataContext of your user control? Please provide some more code of your MainWindow and MainWindowViewModel's to help you further.

Comment: The ChromiumWebBrowser control already implements a Title dependency property http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/F_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_TitleProperty.htm

Comment: Hi @amaitland i have ChromiumWebBrowser control in a user control and my problem is I'm not getting its access in main class tab control where i'm using it. can u help me to fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest you make your question more general to get help from a wider audience, looks like you are wanting to bind a tab title to a child control. Others will be able to help you with this.